# Trying to understand django url namespacing

Tags: python, django, documentation

I was going through the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#removing-hardcoded-urls-in-templates), here they're talking about removing hardcoding in urls so that its easier to modify urls in the future.

This is how a hardcoded url looks like

```
<li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

After removal of hardcoded string

```
<li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

This is all well and done. What's confusing me is the `namespacing` part

Take a look here

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Here the `app_name` variable is introduced to store the app name, `polls` in this case.

But in the URL they have gone and specified `polls` again, so doesn't this mean every URL will have the app name as a hardcoded string?

```
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

So doesn't this mean we're back at square one (the problem with hardcoded urls)

What is the design pattern behind this. Why can't they just look at the app folder and get the app name from there?

Comment: `{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}` doesn't hardcode the URL. If you changed `include('polls/', 'polls.urls'),` to `include('questions/', 'polls.urls'),`, that would change all of the URLs to `/questions/`, `questions/1/`, `/questions/2/results/` and so on without you having to change any templates.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, you're right. Now I feel stupid for asking.